# How to insert a variable into a string using mPDF on Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, mpdf

I am using the library mPDF to create a PDF on Yii2. How do I insert a variable into a string? I have tried many ways so far.

I have the following code:

```
$this->myPdf = (array) $this->myPdf;
$test = array_slice($this->myPdf, -13, 1); //return a value
$html = '
        <h1><a name="top"></a> PDF Test</h1>
        <p>Answer: $test</p>
        ';

$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

$mpdf->Output();
```

The PDF is created however is not showing the value of the $test variable. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [concatenation operator `.`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php). You could also use [double quoted strings.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)

Try this:

```
$this->myPdf = (array) $this->myPdf;
$test = array_slice($this->myPdf, -13, 1); //return a value
$html = '
        <h1><a name="top"></a> PDF Test</h1>
        <p>Answer: '.$test.'</p>
        ';

$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

$mpdf->Output();
```

Also, if this is a user-input based variable, be safe about what goes in!